# Lost iPhone, if "Lost Mode" is on would someone still be able to access messages etc?

Tags: find-my-iphone

I lost my iPhone, but I believe I have "Find My iPhone" switched on. If I turn "Lost Mode" on, using a different Apple device, can messages etc still be accessed by a thief?

Comment: do you have a password on your device?

Comment: "Lost" or "stolen"? If it is lost, then it might be a "finder" rather than a "thief"! Just saying.

Answer (score 1):

No, notifications like messages won't be displayed in the lock screen.

I have just tested it with iOS 10.3.2 with an iPhone 6s. After disabling 'Lost Mode' you will see the messages your phone received in the meantime.

[image: Lost Mode]